# How to transfer sorted linked list to a huffman tree?

Tags: c, list, tree, huffman-code

I used the list to store the input of the user which is string, and sorted by descending order, like this: [Sorted Linked list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPVQm.png)

my struct for list :

```
typedef struct list{
    char ch;
    int freq;
    struct list *next;
}LIST; //Linked list
LIST *L;
```

my struct for tree:

```
typedef struct node{
    char ch;
    int freq;
    struct node *lc,*rc;
}TREE; //Tree
TREE *root;
```

My code to create new node for huffman tree:

```
TREE *newNode(char ch,int freq){
    TREE *n = (TREE*)malloc(sizeof(TREE));

    n->ch = ch;
    n->freq = freq;
    n->rc = n->lc = root;

    return(n);
}
```

My next plan is to transfer the sorted linked list to a huffman tree.

I'm thinking that the function will transfer the linked list like this process:

```
1) head -> [a,6] -> [b,7] -> [c,8] -> [d,9] -> [e,10] -> null

2) head -> [n1,17] -> [c,8] -> [d,9] -> [e,10] -> null
           /\
          /  \
        [a,6] [b,7]

3) head -> [n2,25] -> [d,9] -> [e,10] -> null
           /\
          /  \
     [n1,17] [c,8]
       /\
      /  \
   [a,6] [b,7]

4) head-> [n3,34] -> [e,10] -> null
            / \
      [n2,25] [d,9]
           /\
          /  \
     [n1,17] [c,8]
       /\
      /  \
   [a,6] [b,7]

5) Final huffman tree
   
             [n4,44]
               /  \
          [n3,34] [e,10]
            / \
      [n2,25] [d,9]
           /\
          /  \
     [n1,17] [c,8]
       /\
      /  \
   [a,6] [b,7]
```

Update: I tried to create function:

```
void huffman(){
    LIST *p = L;
    int total = 0;

    TREE *n=root,*q;

    if(p==NULL){
        root = NULL;
        return;
    }
    else{
        while(p!=NULL){
            total = 0;
            total = p->freq + p->next->freq;
            
            if(q==NULL){
                n = newNode(' ',total);
                n->lc = newNode(p->ch,p->freq);
                if(p->next!=NULL){
                    n->rc = newNode(p->next->ch,p->next->freq);
                    p->next->ch = ' ';
                    p->next->freq = total;
                    free(p);
                }
            }else{
                n = root;
                n->lc = q;
                if(p->next!=NULL){
                    n->rc = newNode(p->next->ch,p->next->freq);
                    p->next->ch = ' ';
                    p->next->freq = total;
                    free(p);
                }
            }

            q = n;
            p = p->next;
        }
    }
}
```

But it didn't work.

I think I'm stuck with this part:

```
       connecting this two nodes after connecting 
       first two nodes of linked list
              /        \
         [n1,17] -> [c,8] -> [d,9] -> [e,10] -> null
           /\
          /  \
        [a,6] [b,7]
```

Update: I've decided to create an array of node and transfer it to root node after

```
TREE *a[15];
int i = 0;
void treeNodes(){
    LIST *p = L;
    int total = 0;

    if(p==NULL){
        root = NULL;
        return;
    }
    else{
        while(p!=NULL){
            total = 0;
            total = p->freq + p->next->freq;

            a[i] = newNode(' ',total);
            a[i]->lc = newNode(p->ch,p->freq);
            if(p->next!=NULL){
                a[i]->rc = newNode(p->next->ch,p->next->freq);
                p->next->ch = ' ';
                p->next->freq = total;
                free(p);
            }
            i++;
            p = p->next;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to connect the array of nodes like this:

```
        a[4]
       /    \
    a[3]  
    /   \ 
  a[2]
  /   \ 
a[1] 
/\
```

But I can't figure out how I supposed to do it

Comment: Hi! What is your question?

Comment: Hello sir, I want to know how to transfer the sorted linked list to a tree

Comment: Doesn't your proposed process spell out how you want to do it ? So... do that?

Comment: Sorry sirs, I'm new to use the Tree for program. I managed to map out the process but the problem is to make it to the program

Comment: `if(q==NULL){` <<-- q is not initialized. [Your compiler should issue a warning]

Comment: I initialized q but still not working

Comment: The procedure you outlined doesn’t produce the tree that you’d get via the normal Huffman encoding algorithm. That algorithm works by taking the two least-weight nodes at each point in time and combining them. You do that for your first step (did you mean 13 rather than 18?), but afterwards you’re not combining the two lowest-weight nodes.